# MongoDB Aggregate Last Records and Match some fields to last 30 days

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to get a return with the last/newest values for each $src but also get a 30 day $min and $max on the #inches field.  See the below query

```
        date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=31)

        last_data = collection.aggregate([
        {"$group": {"_id": "$src",
                    "date": {"$last": "$time"},
                    "inches": {"$last": "$inches"},
                    "low":{"$min":"$inches"},
                    "high":{"$max":"$inches"}
                    } }
    ])
```

This works fine except that the LOW and HIGH are all time forever low and high.  I want to restrict the low and high to only pull within the last 30 days. Using the datetime timedelta object if possible.

Below is an example of returning all data from a certain date.  What I am not sure how to do is combine the two queries into one.

```
      data = collection.find({'time':{ "$gte" : (date) }})
```

**UPDATE 1:  Trying the below code out...**

Note: Date is epoch time back 30 days in
today = 1508360994.741111
date = 1505682594.741111

```
collection.aggregate([
         {"$group": {"_id": "$src",
                    "date": {"$last": "$time"},
                    "inches": {"$last": "$inches"},
                    "low": {
                        "$min": {
                            "$cond": [
                                {"time": {"$lte": ["$time", date]}},
                                "$inches",
                                None
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "$max": {
                            "$cond": [
                                {"time": {"$gte": ["$time", date]}},
                                "$inches",
                                None
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    }}
    ])
```

I get a return like this: So it appears it might be working.  I need to do some sanity checks to make sure. 
     {'_id': 'c4028504', 'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 16, 2, 47, 21, 939000), 'inches': 85.0, 'low': 0, 'high': 2007.25},

How would you add a 2nd condition to show only lows > 0. See my ragged attempt below.

```
                   "low": {
                        "$min": {
                            "$cond": [ { "$and" : [
                                { "time": {"$gte": ["$time", date] },
                                { "inches": {"$gt": ["$inches", 0] }
                                ]},
                                "$inches",
                                None
                            ]}
                        }
                    },
```

Comment: Could you perhaps post some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [`min`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/#behavior) & [`max`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#behavior) ignore null and missing values in comparison when all of the values are not null or missing.

You can use above idea to build below query.

"today" is the datetime utc value and "date" is the delta in milliseconds. ( ex: 30 * 86400 *1000 for 30 days).

In essence use conditional operator, calculate the diff between `$time` and "today" and compare to see, if the difference is less than input value (in milliseconds) then `$inches` else `null`.

```
"low": {
  "$min": {
    "$cond": [
      {
        "$lte": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              "$time",
              today
            ]
          },
          date
        ]
      },
      "$inches",
      null
    ]
  }
}
```

You can apply similar logic for `$max` (high) and adjust answer for python.

Comment: I updated my OP with my attempt at implementing the code you provided.  Any idea why i get back the same results for low and high?  Sorry I am still pretty new to mongo trying to get my legs coming from sql.

Comment: No worries.Your syntax is incorrect. Try `"low": {
                        "$min": {
                            "$cond": [{"$lte": ["$time", date]},
                                "$inches",
                                None
                            ]
                        }
                    }`

Comment: I updated my OP with, what i don't get is why it is <= and not >= if I am saying I want all data in the last 30 days and i say cond is >30 days back, wouldn't <= give me previous to the 30 days?

Comment: You may be correct. I wasn't not paying attention to lt and gt. Pls adjust to your needs. To answer your question about only keeping "low" field when it is greater than zero is not possible in latest mongo version but it is possible in upcoming 3.6 version. Something like `low: {$cond: {if: {$eq: [0, "$low"]}, then: "$$REMOVE", else: "$low"}},` in `$project` stage. Reference [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27614)